# 2002 Toyota Sienna Dies right after starting

Tags: toyota, sienna

Help,  My van was running fine the previous day, but when I went to start it the next day it would turn over fine and fire, but it wouldn't continue to run. If I give it gas when it fires it starts, but as soon as I let off of the throttle it dies.

Anyone have any ideas?  I don't think it is the battery as it isn't sluggish at all when it is turning over it just won't run unless I have the throttle pressed.

Comment: It could possibly be either the throttle position sensor (TPS) or the idle air control valve (IAC). There might be other things it could be, this is just what's coming to mind at this second considering your description.

Comment: Just a quick update we finally got it to our mechanic which is two hours away. We did end up replacing the battery since it was heavily corroded and after driving to the mechanic it was no longer dying during idle and was running fine.

Comment: @twreid can you submit that as an answer, please and thank you! If you're still around 2 years later :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what happened, maybe it was bad gas.

Just a quick update we finally got it to our mechanic which is two hours away. We did end up replacing the battery since it was heavily corroded and after driving to the mechanic it was no longer dying during idle and was running fine.

Comment: So you suspect the battery?

Comment: I'm not really sure I think it was the gas because we drove it a good distance to our mechanic and after filling up with gas and driving it the problem stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Mass Airflow tube for any cracks. I had the same problem on mine, it was loose. I tightened it and boom, easy fix .